# Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo

Tags: firebase, android-studio, gradle, firebase-authentication

I spend the last 3 hours trying to fix everything the gradle update broke but I can't find any fix for this one. I tried all the possible solutions I found online.

> Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo

Here is my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example. ..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {

        pickFirst 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.4.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

If someone could please help me, I am feeling really desperate

Comment: try commenting the following: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.4.0'` then build. Gradually from there, try adding the dependencies one by one.

Comment: I did what you said and then tried to clean the build (I have cleaned it before posting this issue) and it looks like it fixed it. Thank you for you answer though !